# Convex lower as opposed to upper bound?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning

**Fundamental Question:** Which of the options give useful surrogate for a non-convex function, the tightest convex lower or the tightest upper bound? (By useful, I mean with theoretical guarantees.)

I know that minimizing a lower bound, gives a lower bound on the minimum of the original objective. However I am not sure what can be argued about minimizing an upper bound.

Reason for the question is confusing observations I have observed:

- Observation 1: Zero-one loss function is non-convex, so every one
  minimizes a tight **"upper bound"** instead such as hinge loss as a
  surrogate. Arguments tell it is a good choice.
- Observation 2: Rank is not convex, so every one  minimizes the
  tightest convex **"lower bound"** (the biconjugate, i.e. the trace
  norm; which is sum of singular values). Arguments tell it is a good
  choice.
- Observation 3: There are cases where sum of a loss and a regularizer
  is optimized, where the former is an upper bound of an original
  loss and the second one, is the lower bound.

Comment: Minimizing the upper bound gives an upper estimate of the minimum of the non-convex function.

Comment: Did you possibly create the tags [tag:lower-bound] and [tag:upper-bound]? Did you clear them with more experienced users? I want to discuss their fate [in Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25171/11619)

Comment: Yes, I think it was me, with the correct spelling though :). Well, not sure how should one clear tags with more experienced users. Does your question mean you think they are not very appropriate? Would be happy to know why.

Comment: user25004 The linked post on meta would be probably better place for your reply and further discussion of the tag. Anyway, if you want that he sees you comment, you should probably have [pinged](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info) @JyrkiLahtonen.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 
Yes, I think it was me, with the correct spelling though :). Well, not sure how should one clear tags with more experienced users. Does your question mean you think they are not very appropriate? Would be happy to know why.

Comment: @user25004 They may be appropriate, or they may not be. However, regardless, always ask on meta before creating a new tag.

Comment: @6005 Oh, I see. Is that the protocol? The tags to be added should be discussed in meta? Sorry I did not know that. :)

Comment: @user25004 Yes, that is the protocol. No worries, just letting you know for next time.